# Вложенный цикл for возвращает неверный результат

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Друзья, подскажите пожалуйста, ато я запутался:
имеются три абзаца с текстом и кнопка. По нажатию на кнопку, нужно записать в начало текста каждого абзаца его нумерацию.

```
   <p class = 'someText'>Some text</p>
   <p class = 'someText'>Some text</p>
   <p class = 'someText'>Some text</p>
   <input id = 'buttonText' type = 'submit'>
```

А вот и сам код:

```
let numList = document.querySelectorAll('.someText');
let outputList = document.querySelector('#buttonText');
outputList.addEventListener('click', function() {
   for (elem of numList) {
      for (var i = 0; i < numList.length; i++) {
      var n = i + 1;
      numList[i].innerHTML = n + numList[i].innerHTML;
      }
    }
  });
```

В итоге он мне выдает:

111Some text
222Some text
333Some text

Он делает больше итераций, чем нужно. Очень нужно понять этот момент. Помогите объяснить. Возможно имеется более лаконичный вариант.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Ну так а зачем вложенный цикл?

Comment: В итоге ты пробегаешься по элементам, а внутри цикла пробегаешься опять по этим элементам. В чём смысл?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let numList = document.querySelectorAll('.someText');
let outputList = document.querySelector('#buttonText');
outputList.addEventListener('click', function() {
   //for (elem of numList) {
      for (var i = 0; i < numList.length; i++) {
      var n = i + 1;
      numList[i].innerHTML = n + numList[i].innerHTML;
      }
  //  }
  });
```

```html
 <p class = 'someText'>Some text</p>
   <p class = 'someText'>Some text</p>
   <p class = 'someText'>Some text</p>
   <input id = 'buttonText' type = 'submit'>
```